# Show that $\arctan(x)$ exists and is differentiable in $(-\pi/2, \pi/2)$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

I'm trying to prove rigorously that $ f(x) = \arctan(x)$ exists and is differentiable in the region $(-\pi/2, \pi/2)$

I know that it's not rigorous to say that $f(\pi/2) = \infty$ and $f(-\pi/2) = -\infty$, because it doesn't make sense and f isn't defined there. So how can I approach the question?

Comment: It is not $\arctan(\pi/2)=+\infty$, but $\arctan(+\infty)=\frac{\pi}{2}$.

Answer (score 1):

The arctangent function is defined as the inverse of the tangent function, that is increasing over over $I=(-\pi/2,\pi/2)$ and differentiable , since:
$$\tan x = \frac{\sin x}{\cos x}$$
is the ratio of two analytic functions over $I$, the latter ($\cos x$) non-vanishing.

Comment: You also need $\tan' > 0$ over $I$. For example $x \mapsto x^3$ is differentiable over $(-1,1)$, but its inverse $x \mapsto x^{1/3}$ is not differentiable in $0$.

Comment: @kahen: true. However, that is straightforward since $\tan'=\frac{1}{\cos^2}>0$.

Comment: Please modify the "sufficient to prove that the function is differentiable" part, which is quite misleading.

Answer (score 1):

$\tan y =x $

$\dfrac{d\tan(y)}{dx}=1$

$\dfrac{1}{\cos^2x}\dfrac{dy}{dx}=1$

$\dfrac{dy}{dx}=\cos^2x$

In a triangle, $\tan y=x$ so $y=\arctan(x)$. The Pythagorean theorem tells
us the length of hypotenuse:

$h=1+x^2$

compute: $\cos y=\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{1+x^2}}$

$\dfrac{d\arctan(x)}{dx}=\dfrac{1}{1+x^2}$

Answer (score 0):

The function $\dfrac1{1+x^2}$ is integrable over $\mathbb R$ (positive and bounded by $1$ and $\dfrac1{x^2}$) so it has an antiderivative, of which the derivative is $\dfrac1{1+x^2}$.